# Prove: the sum of simultaneously diagonalizable transformations is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

> Let $T, S$, linear transformations which are  simultaneously diagonalizable. Prove that $T+S$ is diagonalizable.

I need to rely on the the definition: $T,S$ are called **simultaneously diagonalizable** if there is a basis of $V$ composed by eigen-vectors of both $S$ and $T$.

I'd be glad for a direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm... we know there is a $P$ that diagonalizes $T$ and also diagonalizes $S$. Now what would be your _first_ guess for something that would diagonalize $S+T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose that $PTP^{-1}$ and $PSP^{-1}$ are diagonal.
$$
P(T + S)P^{-1} = PTP^{-1}+PSP^{-1}
$$

---

"How to bounce:" for a vector $v$ in our common basis of eigenvectors,
$$
(T + S)v = Tv + Sv
$$

Comment: I was guided to use another definition (mentioned at my post). How can I "bounce" from my definition to yours?

Comment: @AlonAlon updated accordingly.

Comment: Does it mean that $Tv + Sv = \lambda v + \lambda v = 2\lambda v$?

Comment: Why should $Tv = Sv$?  In general,
$$
Tv + Sv = \lambda v + \mu v
$$
for $\lambda,\mu \in \Bbb C$